# how write protobuf file in golang like this map[string][]string

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have a struct like this in golang:

```
type Request struct {
      Mark     string              
      RemoteIp string              
      Url      string              
      Header   map[string][]string 
      Body     []byte              
}
```

how to convert map[string][]string structure to protobuf message？ I've try out this, but wrong

```
map<string,   repeated string> Header = 4;
```

Comment: You can't do this in a easy way. You need to handle this using additional `struct`

Comment: yes, I can use additional struct, but it would change the interface. PB do not support 'repeat'  in map value in current realization?

Comment: No, It doesn't  support 'repeat'  in map value.